# How to get the file path of a loaded OmegaConf configuration

Tags: python, yaml, fb-hydra, omegaconf

I am using OmegaConf to read a .yaml configuration file (file path is given through hydra).
After I edit it, I want to save the file again. Possibly using:

```
OmegaConf.save(conf, filepath, resolve=True)
```

However, I cannot figure out how to get the file path back in order to save it again.

Is it possible to get it from OmegaConf somehow?  The OmegaConf [documentation](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1_branch/usage.html#serialization) about serializing YAML does not return the same file path for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported. Hydra abstracts away the config files it loads. In fact - those config files may exist inside Python packages, the file system or arbitrary locations backed by specialized plugins.

Comment: I figured as much, but I wanted to make sure there was no way to do it. Thanks!